# Intellij spring mvc support issue

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate version 13 and I have issue with support for spring mvc controllers. I have in my code few controllers. I would assume that they would be listed, shown in Spring tool buttons view. Then I could take a look at their path params etc. I see some screenshots and it worked like that. I have added support for Spring to my project but still controllers are not visible to Intellij. Am i doing something wrong or there is some way to help Intellij detect controllers correctly? I am using spring 4 and java configuration approach.
Best Regards
EDIT:
added example controller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends AbstractBaseController {

    public static final String HOME_ID = "HOME";
    public static final String HOME_URL = "/";
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Override
    protected void initializeRoutes() {
        routes.addRoute(HOME_ID, HOME_URL);
    }

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = HOME_URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.warn("warn");
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a few more details than that, how about a simplified version of a controller showing the problem ?

Comment: added. I would expect that for this controller method home would be shown in intellij spring view. Or the controller will be shown as spring bean.

Comment: I have the same issue, in 14.0.3, I see "no matches found" in my spring MVC tab. my Beans tab is populated with my context configuration classes

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact problem also: IntelliJ 15.0.1

Comment: Related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738

Comment: same issue, latest version to the date of this comment (IDEA 2016.3.5
Build #IU-163.13906.18, built on March 6, 2017) using Spring Boot

Answer (score -1):

Add you your project some properties.

```
Project Structure->Facets->Click(+) and select spring facet from list and then point your module.
```

But if you don't have proper facet please install additional plugins.

```
Settings->Ide settings->Plugins (browse repositories) and there you can search proper plugin.
```

That might help.

Comment: I already have spring support but it still don't resolve the issue.